# How to prove a matrix not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

How can I prove that A*B is not invertible when A (mXn) and B (nXm)

while (m>n)?

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HINT: Complete $A$ to $\tilde A$ by adding  on the right $m-n$ columns consisting of $0$'s, and $B$ to $\tilde B$ by adding below $m-n$ rows consisting of $0$'s. Observe that $A\cdot B = \tilde A \cdot \tilde B$. 
Now clearly $\det \tilde A = \det \tilde B = 0$, so $\det AB = 0$.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by "adding on the right m-n columns 0"?

Comment: @MercyDude: complete it to a square $n\times n$ matrix, with $0$''s

Comment: so can I say that the old A * old B = new A* new B and therefore the det(new A )=0, det(new B) = 0 , and that's why det(a*b)= 0

Comment: @MercyDude: yep

Comment: Thanks, it's so much easier to see it that way!

Comment: @MercyDude , clearly the above proof is correct -in particular, I don't understand the downvote-; yet, orangeskid knows what a mathematical reasoning is; he gives this nonstandard proof for the fun. MercyDude, my friend,  If you do not understand that the best proof (because it is the most natural) is that of AdLibitum, then your future in mathematics does not look very bright.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A Matrix is invertible iff it is square and has full Rank

Answer (score 0):

Because then $\operatorname{rank}(AB)\leqslant n<m$. If $AB$ was invertible, then its rank would be equal to $m$.

Answer (score 0):

The product matrix $A\cdot B$ is the matrix associated to an endomorphism of $\Bbb R^m$ which is--by construction--a composition
$$
\Bbb R^m\longrightarrow\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow\Bbb R^m.
$$
Since $n<m$ the second map cannot be surjective, and so neither the composition. Therefore the composition is not an automorphism and the associated matrix cannot be invertible.